# C# Read console output from bottom to top, until empty line

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application

I'm building C# console application to read device names from serialPort. I managed to print all connected deviceNames to console. Console output looks like this:

```
Scanning...
---------------------------------
Connected devices:

1. DeviceName1
2. DeviceName2
3. DeviceName3
```

Now, how to read output from bottom to top, until first empty line? Than to have `Console.ReadLine()` to give user possibility to choose device by typing number in front of deviceName.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var serialPort = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort()
// Read the data that's in the serial buffer.
var deviceName = serialPort.ReadExisting();

// Write to debug output.
Console.WriteLine($"\n---------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine($"\nConnected devices:\n");
Console.WriteLine(deviceName);

string input;
do
{
    // Here I need posibility for user
    // to type number infront deviceName

} while (deviceName.ToUpper() != null);
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to parse the console output to obtain the desired data? What does your current code look like for reading from serial port and print to console? It sounds like your are over-complicating things a lot.

Comment: I have Bluetooth dongle connected to SerialPort. I issue command `dongle list-device`. Than I get output like in question. Now I need to send message to selected device.

Comment: I updated question with code for reading from SerialPort and printing to console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read from the serial port, you can store it in a string variable.

Then process the string variable by splitting it into an array based on line breaks.

Iterate through the array items and take only those that start with a number, separated by a fullstop.

Those lines that you want, store it into Dictionary, using the index provided by the `ReadExisting()` method as your Dictionary index.
This is to allow you to assign an ID to the device, so that when user select the ID, you can reverse lookup the device by its ID.

Then, loop the Dictionary to display the devices to the console.

Capture the ID selected by the user, and then reverse lookup the device by ID using the Dictionary.

I am assuming that you have means to access the list of devices in an Enumerable list.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Can't simulate the output. So, I assume there is an output from ReadExisting(), and I capture the output to a string variable.
        // var serialPort =  new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort();
        // var outputReadExisting = serialPort.ReadExisting();
        var outputReadExisting = @"Scanning...
-------------------------------- -
Connected devices:

1.DeviceName1
2.DeviceName2
3.DeviceName3";

        var deviceDict = LoadDevicesToDictionary(outputReadExisting);
        DisplayDevices(deviceDict);
        var selectedDevice = PromptUserToSelectDevice(deviceDict);

    }

    private static Dictionary<int, string> LoadDevicesToDictionary(string output)
    {
        var outputLines = output.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine, "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var deviceDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        foreach (var line in outputLines)
        {
            // Skip line if null/whitespace or if it does not contains "." (the index)
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) || !line.Contains("."))
            {
                continue;
            }

            var splitLine = line.Split(new[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            // Skip line if after splitting by number and first part is not an integer (not device index)
            if (splitLine.Length < 2 || !int.TryParse(splitLine[0], out var deviceIndex))
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Add device index as dictionary index, then take remainder string minus the device index and the "."
            deviceDict.Add(deviceIndex, line.Substring(deviceIndex.ToString().Length + 1));
        }
        return deviceDict;
    }

    private static void DisplayDevices(Dictionary<int, string> deviceDict)
    {
        foreach (var device in deviceDict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{device.Key}. {device.Value}");
        }
    }

    private static string PromptUserToSelectDevice(Dictionary<int, string> deviceDict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please select your device (ID): ");
        var selectedId = Console.ReadLine();
        if (!int.TryParse(selectedId, out var idVal)
            || !deviceDict.ContainsKey(idVal))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Please input device ID listed above.");
            return PromptUserToSelectDevice(deviceDict);
        }

        return deviceDict[idVal];
    }
```

Comment: That is nice solution for choosing device after I get it from console output. But I still have problem how to extract device names, like I stated in question.

Comment: @AppleFan Can you share with me, how do you get serialPort object? As in, you're using which library to execute the `dongle list-device` command?

Comment: I updated the question. I'm using System.IO.Ports. That is not the problem... The problem is how to get output from console and create dictionary. If I could take strings from last line, from console output, till first empty line, Than I could parse the string and make the dictionary.

Comment: @AppleFan I tried using `ReadExisting()` myself on my machine, but I can't generate an output. So I mocked the data but it should work the same. I've updated my code. You check and see if it fulfills your need. Mark it as an answer if it solves your problem.